# Swift JSON decoding url

Tags: json, swift, api, decode

I'm starting to hook up my frontend SwiftUI project to a backend and so I'm learning how to make API calls in Swift. I began by trying to use the code in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqo844saoC4) as a workable example. However, I'm running into an error where the `JSONDecoder` is failing to decode the returned data.

What is going on here? My apologies for the blunt question--I'm new to backend development.

---

```
let url = "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?date=2020-01-01&lat=-74.060&lng=40.7128&form"
getData(from: url)
private func getData(from url: String) {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("Something Went Wrong...")
            return
        }
        // data is available
        var result: Response?
        do {
            result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print("failed to convert \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        guard let json = result else {
            return
        }
        print(json.status)
        print(json.results.sunrise)
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

---

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let results: MyResult
    let status: String
}
```

---

```
struct MyResult: Codable {
    let sunrise: String
    let sunset: String
    let solar_noon: String
    let day_length: Int
    let civil_twilight_begin: String
    let nautical_twilight_begin: String
    let nautical_twilight_end: String
    let astronomical_twilight_begin: String
    let astronomical_twilight_end: String
}
```

---

Note that I'm not following the video exactly. I took the `getData` function out of a
`ViewController` class because I didn't think it was relevant--I'm not dealing with any views at this point, and I don't want to be either. I also took the liberty to testing the code in a Swift Playground. I don't know whether that will influence things.

Comment: Print error instead of error.localizedDescription. You’ll get more detail about what the issue is.

Comment: You all have string elements in the results guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue in your code is your `day_length` data type. You are trying to decode an `Int` while the data returned is a `String`. Besides that it is Swift naming convention to use camelCase to name your struct properties. All you need to do to match your json is to set your JSONDecoder object `keyDecodingStrategy` property to `.convertFromSnakeCase`. And when printing the decoding error you should print the `error` not its `localizedDescription` as already mentioned in comments:

---

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let results: MyResult
    let status: String
}
```

---

```
struct MyResult: Codable {
    let sunrise: String
    let sunset: String
    let solarNoon: String
    let dayLength: String
    let civilTwilightBegin: String
    let nauticalTwilightBegin: String
    let nauticalTwilightEnd: String
    let astronomicalTwilightBegin: String
    let astronomicalTwilightEnd: String
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let json = """
{"results":{"sunrise":"12:00:01 AM","sunset":"12:00:01 AM","solar_noon":"9:20:25 AM","day_length":"00:00:00","civil_twilight_begin":"12:00:01 AM","civil_twilight_end":"12:00:01 AM","nautical_twilight_begin":"12:00:01 AM","nautical_twilight_end":"12:00:01 AM","astronomical_twilight_begin":"12:00:01 AM","astronomical_twilight_end":"12:00:01 AM"},"status":"OK"}
"""
```

---

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let result = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: Data(json.utf8))
    print(result)
} catch {
    print("Decoding error:", error)
}
```

---

This will print:

> Response(results: MyResult(sunrise: "12:00:01 AM", sunset: "12:00:01 AM", solarNoon: "9:20:25 AM", dayLength: "00:00:00", civilTwilightBegin: "12:00:01 AM", nauticalTwilightBegin: "12:00:01 AM", nauticalTwilightEnd: "12:00:01 AM", astronomicalTwilightBegin: "12:00:01 AM", astronomicalTwilightEnd: "12:00:01 AM"), status: "OK")